# R bar plot rename x axis ticks

Tags: r, ggplot2, rename, boxplot

I have a problem in renaming the x-axis ticks of my boxplot.

I have the following data.

```
CountWorkStudy          <- 14
CountLeisureSport       <- 26
CountSleepingRelax      <- 7
CountUnterwegs          <- 7

ActivityCountAll <- c(CountWorkStudy,CountLeisureSport,CountSleepingRelax,CountUnterwegs)
Names <- c(1,2,3,4)
#Names <- c("WorkStudy","LeisureSport","SleepingRelax","Unterwegs")
AllActivity <- cbind(ActivityCountAll,Names)
AllActivity <- as.data.frame(AllActivity)
```

Now I want to rename the x-axis ticks in the boxplot, however the result is a boxplot without any ticks.

```
ggplot(AllActivity, aes(x=Names, y=ActivityCountAll)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")+ scale_x_discrete(labels=c("1" = "Work", "2" = "SportLeisure","3" = "SleepRelax","4" = "Unterwegs"))
```

[image: boxplot without a axis ticks]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this. The issue is that your x value is defined as numeric so the discrete scaling is not working. You can format it as factor in order to get the desired plot. Here the code:

```
#Code
ggplot(AllActivity, aes(x=factor(Names), y=ActivityCountAll)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")+
  scale_x_discrete(labels=c("1" = "Work", "2" = "SportLeisure","3" = "SleepRelax","4" = "Unterwegs"))
```

Output:

[image]

Or for further customization:

```
#Code2
ggplot(AllActivity, aes(x=factor(Names), y=ActivityCountAll)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")+
  scale_x_discrete(labels=c("1" = "Work", "2" = "SportLeisure","3" = "SleepRelax","4" = "Unterwegs"))+
  xlab('Names')
```

Output:

[image]